# Hex/Decimal/Ascii Editor (Save Game Editor)

Tags: editor

In windows there are some tools to edit Saved Games, for example the old UGE (Universal Game Editor) and Cheat Engine. I am looking for a hex/decimal editor that can read this files and find/replace values. For example changing gold,hp, etc...

The Editor should have the ability see signed/unsigned 1byte/2byte/4byte information as well as hex/decimal notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used anything like that in a long time, but here is a web page with quite a few possible choices: http://www.linuxlinks.com/Software/Editors/Hex/